# Putting a cache infront of distributed redis cache

Tags: java, caching, redis, ehcache

I have a java enterprise application that does a lot of fetching of cached data.
The data is stored in a 3 server redis cluster and is accessed by 5 backend api nodes.

I am seeing that we are putting alot of stress on the redis caches, which is why I am wondering if it is dumb to put a in-mem cache such as Ehcache in front of redis. With this solution I would set the TTL to be very short in the Ehcache.

Is this a common solution or is it more reasonable to look into expanding the redis cluster?

Comment: Using an integrated tool could make more sense, something like Geode/GemFire or InfiniSpan that take care of WAN/LAN (local/remote) replication for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thing you are talking about is called *near cache*. It's absolutely legit solution in some cases. It provides trade-off between performance and freshness of the values. However you can only consider this option if seeing a bit stale values is tolerable in your case. Just FYI, [Apache Ignite](https://ignite.apache.org/) supports this feature out of the box.